# Python Bot Telegram - Problem with command invoked externally

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I've created a Telegram bot with a custom command named "command1".

The command is executed perfectly through Telegram interface:
[working-command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwxKc.png)
But, if I wanted to invoke the command from external service the command not working:
[error-command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Twon.png)

Here the bot code:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

API_TOKEN = '12345'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)


# Handle '/start' and '/help'
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    logger.info('send_welcome')
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, "Hi there, I am Example bot.")


# Handle '/command1'
@bot.message_handler(commands=['command1'])
def command1(message):
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'command1 executed!')
    logger.info('command1')

bot.polling()
```

This is the "external service":

```
import requests

def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):

    bot_token = '12345'
    bot_chatID = '8200000001'
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&text=' + bot_message

    response = requests.get(send_text)

    return response.json()


test = telegram_bot_sendtext("/command1") # tested also with "command1" sintax
print(test)
```

Why the command is not executed when it is invoked externally?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to message one bot with another bot?

Comment: @Groosha No. The "external service" is a simple python script executed from a custom CRM.

Comment: @Franceso, I see, but you're trying to execute a Bot API command (to send the message as bot) to another bot?